# If-statement to prevent cartoon to be placed outside a predefiend area

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm having trouble getting this if-statement below to properly do what I want it to.
This "Baddie" being mentioned in here is a cartoon which is moving around in a box by pressing the arrowkeys that is `400px` width, `300px` height.

This function is going to prevent him from moving outside this box but my issue is that he can move out of the box even with my variable being `movable = false;`

```
var isBaddieMovable = function(moveLeft, moveTop) {
        var movable, newLeft, newTop, max;
        console.log("Checking if baddie collided with the content walls");
        movable = true;
        // Get baddie's new position if moved
        newLeft = left + moveLeft*step;
        newTop = top + moveTop*step;
        console.log("Checking collision at", newLeft, newTop);

        // Left wall collide check - check if newLeft outside content
        var condition = false;
        if(newLeft < 0) {
            movable = false;
            console.log("Baddie collided with left wall");
        }
        condition = false;
        // Top wall collide check - check if newTop is outside content
        if(newTop < 0) {
            movable = false;
            console.log("Baddie collided with top wall");
        }
        // Right wall collide check
        max = 400;
        if(newLeft + baddie.offsetWidth > max) {
            movable = false;
            console.log("Baddie collided with right wall");
        }
        // Bottom wall collide check
        max = 300;
        if(newTop + baddie.offsetHeight > max) {
            movable = false;
            console.log("Baddie collided with bottom wall");
        }

        // Return if baddie collided
        return movable;
    };
```

I can see in from the `console.log()` that the function is finding out the Baddie collided with the wall, but he's still going through the walls even with the `movable = false` is set.

```
Console:
Baddie will step 50 pixels each move
Baddie starts at 0,0
37 was pressed
Checking if baddie collided with the content walls
Checking collision at -50 0
Baddie collided with left wall
```

Is this enough information to help me out?

Edit:
As someone mentioned, I have added the function for the movement here:

```
var moveBaddie = function(moveLeft, moveTop) {

        left += moveLeft*step;
        top += moveTop*step;

        baddie.style.left = left + "px";
        baddie.style.top = top + "px";
    };
```

Edit 2:
This is the Switch-case that calls the functions `isBaddieMovable()` and `moveBaddie()`

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    var baddie, content;
    var step, left, top;

    baddie = document.getElementById("baddie");
    content = document.getElementById("content");

    step = baddie.offsetWidth;
    console.log("Baddie will step " + step + " pixels each move");

    // Gets starting position of baddie
    left = baddie.offsetLeft;
    top = baddie.offsetTop;
    console.log("Baddie starts at " + left + "," + top);

    /* ------------------------------------
     * EVENTS
     */
    // Triggers action on keypress
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
        var key;
        // Gets what key was pressed as number
        key = event.keyCode || event.which;
        console.log(key + " was pressed");

        // Switch case to decide where baddie is to go
        switch(key) {
            case 37: {
                isBaddieMovable(-1, 0);
                return moveBaddie(-1, 0)+turnLeft();    
                    }
                break;
            case 38:{
                isBaddieMovable(0, -1);
                return moveBaddie( 0, -1);  
                break;
                    }   
            case 39: {
                isBaddieMovable(1, 0);
                return moveBaddie(1, 0)+turnRight();
                break;
                }
            case 40: {
                isBaddieMovable(0, 1);
                return moveBaddie(0, 1);

                break;
                }
            default:
                console.log("Nothing happened with the gameboard");

                return true;
        }
        // Baddie action was performed - prevent button default
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Edit:
Turns out it wasn't the function failing.
It was my switch-case that wasn't setup correctly.
Changed to this and now it's working!

```
switch(key) {
        case 37: 
            if (isBaddieMovable(-1, 0))
            return moveBaddie(-1, 0)+turnLeft();

            break;
        case 38:
            if (isBaddieMovable(0, -1))
            return moveBaddie( 0, -1);
            break;

        case 39: 
            if (isBaddieMovable(1, 0))
            return moveBaddie(1, 0)+turnRight();
            break;
        case 40: 
            if (isBaddieMovable(0, 1))
            return moveBaddie(0, 1);
            break;
```

Comment: set a breakpoint, and debug

Comment: how do you call the function?

Comment: What values have variables `left, top, step`? Can you add it to `console.log()` ?

Comment: You'll need to show the function that moves the character. (Also, unrelated side note, the `movable` variable is redundant since you could just return false instead of setting it.)

Comment: For what reasons uses variable `condition` ?

Comment: You're just calling `isBaddieMovable()` but you don't do anything with the return value. Why do you suppose it would prevent the code from advancing?

Comment: @Juhana Hm, yes you're absolutely right. Would it be possible to use an if-statement inside my switch-case on each case?

Example:
´switch(key) {
            case 37: {
                if (isBaddieMovable(-1, 0));
                return moveBaddie(-1, 0)+turnLeft();    
                    }
                break;´

Comment: Yes, except without the semicolon after the `if`. Also, the square brackets inside the cases are unnecessary.

Comment: @Juhana Yay! It's working! I can't thank you enough! I've wasted far more hours than I want to admit on this issue! I've been trying to change most of my function without success. No wonder it didn't work! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to do that , first get your movement values then test it after your switchcase and be sure your `isBaddieMovable` return true of false... and if it return true perform a movement...

I hope it will help.

```
var movementToDo = {left:0,up:0};
var couldMove = false;

switch(key) {
        case 37: 
             movementToDo.left= -1;
             movementToDo.up = 0;
            break;
        case 38:
             movementToDo.left= 0;
             movementToDo.up = -1;
            break; 
        case 39: 
             movementToDo.left= 1;
             movementToDo.up = 0;
            break; 
        case 40: 
             movementToDo.left= 0;
             movementToDo.up = 1;
            break; 
        default:
            console.log("Nothing happened with the gameboard");

            return true;
    }

    if(isBaddieMovable(movementToDo.left,movementToDo.up)){
      moveBaddie(movementToDo.left,movementToDo.up);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could return false right away to avoid the chance that someone goes wrong with that variable. But when i see your code i think you should search the problem in the code which uses the check instead.

```
var isBaddieMovable = function(moveLeft, moveTop) {
        var newLeft, newTop, max;
        console.log("Checking if baddie collided with the content walls");
        // Get baddie's new position if moved
        newLeft = left + moveLeft*step;
        newTop = top + moveTop*step;
        console.log("Checking collision at", newLeft, newTop);

        // Left wall collide check - check if newLeft outside content

        if(newLeft < 0) {
            console.log("Baddie collided with left wall");
            return false;
        }

        if(newTop < 0) {
            console.log("Baddie collided with top wall");
            return false;
        }
        // Right wall collide check
        max = 400;
        if(newLeft + baddie.offsetWidth > max) {
            console.log("Baddie collided with right wall");
            return false;
        }
        // Bottom wall collide check
        max = 300;
        if(newTop + baddie.offsetHeight > max) {
            console.log("Baddie collided with bottom wall");
            return false;
        }

        // Return if baddie collided
        return true;
    };
```